# How to prefix all requests with ~username?

Tags: linux, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm testing moving my site to a new Linux server using cPanel which requires you to put in your IP and username (e.g. `http://123.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/`). The problem is, all my image/JS/CSS links use paths like `/css/style.css` or `/images/picture.jpg` so none of the styles, scripts or images show up properly.

How do I set up a `RewriteRule` to prefix ~username to all requests?

Answer (score 0):

Before moving site, if it was working with only domain name and with redirection then now it should also work with server IP and username, Make sure the permissions and ownership of  /css/style.css or /images/picture.jpg are correct.

Also check it once adding exact path manually like  'http://123.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/css/style.css'.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around the issue by setting the domain to a dedicated IP instead of shared, so I could access the site using 123.xxx.xxx.xxx instead of 123.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username.